# Употребление "влачить на"

Tags: выбор-слов

Всегда думал, что можно сформулировать как "влачить на чём-то, ком-то", но, сверившись со словарём, не нашёл такого варианта употребления.

Так действительно неграмотно сказать или всё же можно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Влачить - старая форма глагола "волочить" (тащить волоком, тянуть лежащее на земле). Сейчас употребляется  преимущественно в составе устойчивых выражений (в переносном смылсе: "влачить жалкое существование" и т.п.), а также в поэтических текстах и возвышенных речах. Поэтому вряд ли возможен контекст с таким предлогом, разве что найдётся какой-нибудь странный псеводопоэтический изыск "на худосочнейших харчах влачил своё существованье". А форма "волочить" вполне допускает "на чём": "Чучело начинают волочить на шкуре или веревке ..." (Г.П. Дементьев Охота с ловчими птицами, КОИЗ 1935). Это может означать, что то, "на чём" волочат (гораздо реже "на ком"), тащат волоком по земле, а уже поверх него закреплено то, "что (кого)" волочат на непосредственно перемещаемом волоком предмете. В случае же "на веревке" волочат по земле сам предмет посредством верёвки.

Comment: Покажите мне вообще глагол, который *не* допускает подобного. Это по сути дела обстоятельство места или орудия. Говорить о том, что глагол имеет такое управление как0то не приходится.

Answer (score 5):

> ...но, сверившись со словарём, не нашёл такого варианта употребления.

[**Есть и в словарях:**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слава это не то. Здесь, во-первых нет жесткой связи с влачить, а во-вторых только "на себе" и возможно.

Comment: _behemothus: а во-вторых только "на себе" и возможно_. === Нет, не только _на себе_.

 В книгах встречается _влачить на плечах, на спинах, на ногах, на лошадях_…  https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%B0%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=GxzTVuS7GsansAHZqKjABw#q=%22%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%B0%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&start=0

Answer (score 0):

Примерчик бы привели фразы с управлением, которое Вы считаете допустимым. Трудно гадать умозрительно.

Вообще глагол "влачить" в современном языке используется почти исключительно в выражении "влачить [жалкое] существование" и подобных. Куда тут предлог НА цеплять, да еще с предложным падежом, я что-то не представляю.